# Does SQL Server execute many UPDATE requests on single row as ONE single UPDATE?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

I have an AFTER UPDATE trigger on one Db table. -This is for INSERTing Audit logs into an audit table.

And I have 3 parallel applications running independently and they do update on the same record.

My Problem is, I see only one Audit log even though the row is updated 3 times from 3 different applications.

**QUESTION:**
Is it possible that when SQL Server receives couple of UPDATEs on one record, it executes them as one UPDATE operation? And as a UPDATE Trigger is fired only once?

Comment: No, each `UPDATE` will be executed within a separate transaction. If you're seeing missing audit/change tracking information (if that's what your trigger is for) it's more likely that your trigger doesn't properly deal with multiple rows. We'd do a lot better if your question told us what issues/symptoms you currently have that made you suspect that something odd was happening.

Comment: I have updated the question and elaborate the problem a bit more.

Comment: What do you mean by: "your trigger doesn't properly deal with multiple rows. " -Is there any guideline or a resource on such cases? I would appreciate if you can point out? Thanks!!!

Comment: [Using the inserted and deleted Tables](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214435(v=sql.80).aspx). Note that they're described as *tables* - therefore, if you've got any code that does, say, `select @variable = column from inserted` then that's just plain wrong - there can be *multiple* rows (or no rows) in `inserted` and `deleted`. You have to write code in your trigger that copes with multiple rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server will never treat those updates as one update of the same row (it's not a record actually, but that's a different story).

First, the 3 applications have 3 different connections so they will come in as 3 updates.
Second, when the first update reaches SQL Server, the row will be locked until this updates finishes and is written to the transaction log. Then the second update can do his job, and so on..

Therefore, the TRIGGER will always fire three times (if the updates are committed).

Comment: After reading your update to the question: maybe the INSERT in the TRIGGER isn't doing his job? Can you share (part of) the code that's used for the trigger?

Answer (score 1):

Three updates from three sources will run in three transactions and trigger an update trigger three times.  SQL Server will use locking to limit interactions between the three transactions.